# Load-time weaving and java -jar

Tags: aop, aspectj

Is it possible to add the aspectj load-time agent when start a program with -jar ?

With Jetty, if I start

```
java -javaagent:aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar -classpath toto.jar -jar start.jar
```

The aspectj is not apply. But I if call

```
java -javaagent:aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar -classpath toto.jar;start.jar org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main
```

all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `-jar` and LTW seems to be that there is something different with the classloading order compared to the `-cp (...) my.MainClass` approach. Probably the JAR specified with `-jar` is loaded before the weaver can see the aspects and `META-INF/aop-ajc.xml` in the aspect JAR on the classpath. I found a workaround, but it is not nice: You can put the aspect JAR on the JVM's boot classpath, but in this case the aspects are loaded even before the weaving agent. Thus you also have to add `aspectjrt.jar` to the boot classpath:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:aspect.jar;lib\aspectjrt.jar -javaagent:lib\aspectjweaver.jar -jar application.jar
```

Considering this circumstance, I guess it is preferable to add the application JAR to the normal classpath and specify the main class manually. But it is a matter of taste and whether you know the main class name when starting your application.