# Load Time Weaving in Spring Framework not logging properly

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, load-time-weaving

Is Load time Weaving(LTW) good choice for Enterprise Level Application with JSF as user interface and containing 6k+ classes?
    Performance metrics has be to generated for the whole application but it is not able to generate for JSF managed Bean like LoginMBean. However @Component is there so is it possible that it can work with AspectJ(LTW)? aop.xml is added and aspectJWeaver path is also added to vm arguments.

```xml
<aspectj>
    <weaver
    options=" -verbose -showWeaveInfo -Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true -Xreweavable">
        <include within="com.x.login..*" />
        <include within="com.x.aspects.Aspect" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.x.aspects.Aspect" />   
    </aspects>
</aspectj
```

```java
package com.x.login;

@Component
@Scope("session")
public class LoginMBean extends AbstractMbean {
    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService ;

    public void loginUserData(){
    LoginInfo info= new LoginInfo();
    //setter for info object
    //some nested method calls
    loginService.insertLoginData(info);

   }
}
```

```java
package com.x.login.service.impl;

@Service("LoginService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService{
    @Autowired
    GenericCrudService  genericCrudService ;

    public void insertLoginData(LoginInfo info){
      //some nested method calls
      try{
        genericCrudService.saveEntity(info);
      }catch(Exception e){
      //log exception
      }
    }        

}
```

```java
package com.x.aspect.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.x" })
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving=AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
public class AspectConfig {


}
```

```java
package com.x.aspects; 

@Component 
@Aspect
public class Aspects {
    private static Logger Logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(Aspects.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && cflow(execution(* com.x.login..*(..)))")
    public void methodsToBeProfiled() {}

    @Around("methodsToBeProfiled()")
    public Object methodsToBeProfiled(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch(getClass().getSimpleName());
        try {
            sw.start(point.getSignature().getName());
            return point.proceed();
        } finally {
            sw.stop();
            Logger.info("Elapsed Time, Package Name, Method Name");
            Logger.info(sw.prettyPrint());
            Logger.info("Package Name: " + point.getStaticPart());
        }
    }
}
```

AspectJ Log :

```
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@17c8dbdf] info register aspect com.x.aspects.Aspects
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@17c8dbdf] info register aspect org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@17c8dbdf] info register aspect org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@5e68f202] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.x.aspects.Aspects.methodsToBeProfiled())' in Type 'com.x.aspects.Aspects' (Aspects.java:36) advised by around advice from 'com.x.aspects.Aspects' (Aspects.java) [with runtime test]
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@5e68f202] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(java.lang.String com.x.login.PSMVProperties.getMultiDb())' in Type 'com.x.login.PSMVProperties' (PSMVProperties.java:27) advised by around advice from 'com.x.aspects.Aspects' (Aspects.java) [with runtime test]
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@5e68f202] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.x.login.MultiDatabase.loadAEFormRestrictions(com.x.qnccore.service.GenericCrudService, java.lang.String, org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext))' in Type 'com.x.login.MultiDatabase' (MultiDatabase.java:275) advised by around advice from 'com.x.aspects.Aspects' (Aspects.java) [with runtime test]
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@5e68f202] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.x.login.QuestionMBean.setRecordLock(boolean))' in Type 'com.x.login.QuestionMBean' (QuestionMBean.java:146) advised by around advice from 'com.x.aspects.Aspects' (Aspects.java) [with runtime test]
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@5e68f202] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(java.lang.String com.x.login.RequestPojo.getTenantid())' in Type 'com.x.login.RequestPojo' (RequestPojo.java:18) advised by around advice from 'com.x.aspects.Aspects' (Aspects.java) [with runtime test]
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@5e68f202] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.x.login.RequestPojo.setTenantid(java.lang.String))' in Type 'com.x.login.RequestPojo' (RequestPojo.java:23) advised by around advice from 'com.x.aspects.Aspects' (Aspects.java) [with runtime test]
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@17c8dbdf] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.x.login.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl.insertLoginData(com.x.agx.admin.bus.entity.LoginInfo))' in Type 'com.x.login.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl' (LoginServiceImpl.java:427) advised by around advice from 'com.x.aspects.Aspects' (Aspects.java) [with runtime test]
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@17c8dbdf] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(java.util.List com.x.login.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl.getFailedLoginAttemptUsingIp(java.util.HashMap))' in Type 'com.x.login.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl' (LoginServiceImpl.java:442) advised by around advice from 'com.x.aspects.Aspects' (Aspects.java) [with runtime test]
```

```
spring-config.xml

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" />
```

Metrics log

```
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00003  100%  insertLoginData

2019-07-30 15:14:19,550 INFO c.a.a.Aspects [http-nio-8080-exec-10] Package Name: execution(void com.x.login.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl.insertLoginData(LoginInfo))
2019-07-30 15:14:19,554 INFO c.a.a.Aspects [http-nio-8080-exec-10] Elapsed Time, Package Name, Method Name
2019-07-30 15:14:19,555 INFO c.a.a.Aspects [http-nio-8080-exec-10] StopWatch 'Aspects': running time (millis) = 4
```

LoginMBean is jsf managed for login.xhtml.
Is it JSF issue or because of wrong pointcut?
LoginMBean is not appearing in woven classes.
Please help what is wrong above.I am unable to get
performance metrics for any method in LoginMBean class.

Comment: For LoginServiceImpl logs are getting generated however is not generated for LoginMBean. Thus for service level pointcut is working. but not for LoginMBean. and in aop.xml   <include within="com.x.aspects.Aspects" />

Comment: Hello. I took the liberty to split your mash-up of code in to smaller chunks (one per class), fixed indentation, added syntax highlighting and reordered the pointcut in the aspect to come before the advice method using it. All that makes the code a bit more readable, but as for your question, I have difficulties understanding the problem, especially because your pointcut is package name sensitive but you provide no package names in your code. Also you don't share any code calling and methods you want to intercept, so I am failing to see why you use `cflow()`.

Comment: Last, but not least you say you want to use AspectJ with LTW. If that is true, aspects should work independently of any Spring components for any kind of POJO. If you are using Spring AOP, it really only works for Spring components, but in that case `cflow()` would not work because only AspectJ supports it. Maybe you can edit your question and explain more and show more code. Please don't add important information as comments, update the question and then notify me of the update in a comment.

Comment: What exactly was unclear about me asking you to edit your question instead of commenting? A sample correction made in a comment is not visible when reading the question. Please move all the information from your comments into the question and delete the comments. In general, let your code speak, ideally provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to make your problem reproducible. From your prose I cannot get all the information I need to help you, unfortunately. You didn't even answer my question about package names.

Comment: Another question: You added the weaver option `-showWeaveInfo`. Can you please verify if your `LoginMBean` class has actually been woven? You can also post AspectJ weaver log output here by editing your question.

Comment: added aspectj log file. spring-config for classes using  xml configuration and @ EnableLoadTimeWeaving for rest classes  that are using annotations.

Comment: cflow () I have used for nested method call.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your log, it looks like `LoginMBean` is not exposed to the AspectJ weaver. At least I do not see any `weaveinfo ... in Type 'com.x.login.LoginMBean'`. So

- either the class is loaded and woven later (you can grep your log for `weaveinfo.*LoginMBean` further down the log after you are sure the class was loaded and used by JSF)
- or it is not woven at all (if you do not find such a log entry). Then you are having a classloader issue, i.e. somehow the AspectJ weaving agent was not registered on the classloader responsible for loading `LoginMBean`. Then it would be interesting to know which application server you are using and what your command JVM line looks like (should be something with `-javaagent:...`.

Please follow up on this answer either via commenting or via updating your question with more information. Ideally, produce and publish an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub.

Comment: LoginMBean is not woven at all. I am using Apache Tomcat 8.5 and vm arguments are Djavaagent="D:\Maven_Repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar"

Comment: Does it matter that bean is session scoped or singleton for AspectJ(LTW) to work? can you suggest some better way for performance metrics to be generated for big application that too not only for interface level methods but also nested method calls? suppose we have around 7k+ classes inside package then package level pointcut will firsts load all these and that is time consuming.

Comment: AspectJ does not care about your bean scope, it has no knowledge of it. What is important is that the weaving agent is loaded before all relevant classloaders so as to be able to decorate them by weaving functionality. Maybe you can try [putting it on the boot classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849874/1082681). Without an MCVE it is really just speculation. If you want to avoid slow start-up time, use AspectJ Maven plugin and do compile-time weaving.

Comment: The best thanks would be to describe what you did and if/how your problem was solved. You still have not accepted and upvoted my answer, so is there any further problem?

Comment: it is helpful however I think problem is not at all with Aspects as service level logs I am getting fully. I m thinking to switch to compile time as LoginMBean is still not loaded. So as application is very big it might be problem with some code or flow.i have still not figured out, will keep update if i find any solution.

Comment: I will publish an MCVE on Github. As I am stuck